# An item with the same key has already been added error when converting to .Net 4.5 Framework

Tags: asp.net, .net, linq, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I hope someone can help me with this because it is driving me  crazy.
I have a project that I am converting from a website project created in vs 2010 (4.0 framework) to a web app project in vs 2012. All of it has worked relatively well except for the some the parts that use the entity framework. It builds fine, but when I go to the page it throws the error "An item with the same key has already been added" when I use linq on the entities. It works just fine in VS 2010, both hitting the same database.

Code Throwing the Error:

```
Using Context As New AwardEntities
            Dim listAward = From award In Context.AwardInfoes
                            Select award

            cmbAwardList.DataTextField = "AWARDTITLE"
            cmbAwardList.DataValueField = "AWARDID"
            cmbAwardList.DataSource = listAward
            cmbAwardList.DataBind()
        End Using
```

Stack trace:

```
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemAttributeAssemblyLoader.LoadRelationshipTypes()
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemAttributeAssemblyLoader.LoadTypesFromAssembly()
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemAssemblyLoader.Load()
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemAttributeAssemblyLoader.Load()
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssemblyCache.LoadAssembly(Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, ObjectItemLoadingSessionData loadingData)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssemblyCache.LoadAssembly(Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, KnownAssembliesSet knownAssemblies, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Action`1 logLoadMessage, Object& loaderCookie, Dictionary`2& typesInLoading, List`1& errors)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemCollection.LoadAssemblyFromCache(ObjectItemCollection objectItemCollection, Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Action`1 logLoadMessage)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.LoadFromAssembly(Assembly assembly, Action`1 logLoadMessage)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.LoadFromAssembly(Assembly assembly)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.TryUpdateEntitySetMappingsForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.UpdateEntitySetMappingsForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Select[TSource,TResult](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 selector)
   at Webtool.Award.populateAwardCmb() in C:\TFS_Sandbox\WebToolTest\WebTool_1_0\Webtool\Award.aspx.vb:line 106
   at Webtool.Award.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\TFS_Sandbox\WebToolTest\WebTool_1_0\Webtool\Award.aspx.vb:line 26
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Thanks for any help that can be provided.

Edit:

This is where the relations are added to EdmRelationshipAttribute

```
<Assembly: EdmSchemaAttribute("54fb0601-c7ee-4437-8467-f4a378fcff86")>
#Region "EDM Relationship Metadata"
<Assembly: EdmRelationshipAttribute("Award_Model", "FK_AwardInfo_AwardAffilliationLU", "AwardAffilliationLU", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.One, GetType(AwardAffiliationLU), "AwardInfo", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.Many, GetType(AwardInfo), True)>
<Assembly: EdmRelationshipAttribute("Award_Model", "FK_AwardDates_AwardInfo", "AwardInfo", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.One, GetType(AwardInfo), "AwardDates", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.Many, GetType(AwardDate), True)>
<Assembly: EdmRelationshipAttribute("Award_Model", "FK_AwardDocs_AwardDates", "AwardDates", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.One, GetType(AwardDate), "AwardDocs", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.Many, GetType(AwardDoc), True)>
<Assembly: EdmRelationshipAttribute("Award_Model", "FK_AwardValues_AwardDates", "AwardDates", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.ZeroOrOne, GetType(AwardDate), "AwardValues", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.Many, GetType(AwardValue), True)>
<Assembly: EdmRelationshipAttribute("Award_Model", "FK_AwardDocs_AwardInfo", "AwardInfo", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.One, GetType(AwardInfo), "AwardDocs", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.Many, GetType(AwardDoc), True)>
<Assembly: EdmRelationshipAttribute("Award_Model", "FK_AwardValues_AwardInfo", "AwardInfo", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.One, GetType(AwardInfo), "AwardValues", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.Many, GetType(AwardValue), True)>
<Assembly: EdmRelationshipAttribute("Award_Model", "FK_AwardValues_AwardPlaceLU", "AwardPlaceLU", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.One, GetType(AwardPlaceLU), "AwardValues", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.Many, GetType(AwardValue), True)>
<Assembly: EdmRelationshipAttribute("Award_Model", "FK_AwardRecipients_AwardDates", "AwardDate", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.One, GetType(AwardDate), "AwardRecipient", System.Data.Metadata.Edm.RelationshipMultiplicity.Many, GetType(AwardRecipient), True)>

#End Region
```

Comment: Have you tried to see what happens if you execute the query right away, without waiting for UI to bind on it? Just for fun try setting the datasource to listAward.ToList() and see what happens.

Comment: For some reason a duplicate relationship name is added to `SessionData.TypesInLoading` (a dictionary). These names are collected from `EdmRelationshipAttribute`s that originate from the store model, so normally they can't have duplicates. But as a first forensic effort I'd check for the occurrence of this attribute in your code base.

Comment: @GertArnold Searching through the code I found where the relationships are added to EdmRelationshipAttribute. I'm not seeing any duplicates. I'll edit the question to show the results.

Comment: Well, this gets a bit weird. W.r.t. entity framework, did you change more than just the VS version, maybe also the .Net version? Or EF version itself?

Comment: I changed it from .net 4.0 to 4.5. The entity framework version is the same though, I just copied all the project files to the new project folder, included all the files and had them converted to a web application.

Comment: @daysanew Maybe you should try to regenerate the code from the edmx.

Comment: @GertArnold I've already tried that. Deleted the files and went through the whole process to rebuild the model. Using LINQ I get the same result. If I try to using an entitydatasource I get a type conversion error (though I'm thinking if I get past the type conversion error I may hit the duplicate key error).

Comment: @Crono1981 I just tried that and it threw the same error.